# What is the best way to implement authorization/access control in a Spring 3 MVC web application?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-security, access-control, spring-annotations

Buddies,

I'm about to develop a web application using Spring 3 MVC as web framework, Hibernate Annotations as ORM framework However, I'm facing a problem to design a good database based access control for this application. In my work we are used to design this way:

- **(CompanyName)User.java** - A class that means a **User** in the system
- **Profile.java** - A class that means a **ROLE** in the system in a **N-N** relationship with                **(CompanyName)User**. With **ROLE**, I mean an user group such as **(ADMIN,ANONYMOUS,CUSTOMER SERVICE USER, etc.)**
- **UserProfile.java** - A class that means a relationship between an **User** and a **Profile**. It represents a **JOIN TABLE** for a **N-N** relationship in the database.
- **Module.java** - A class that means a **MODULE** in the web application. Each module is made of unlimited features, but each features can only be related to one **MODULE**. For example, an **USER AUTHENTICATION** feature would be related to a **SECURITY** or **AUTHENTICATION** module. Modules are controllers in the application tagged with @Controller.
- **Feature.java** - A class that represents a **FEATURE** in the application. Each feature is made of one or many operations. For example, USER MANAGEMENT is a FEATURE. And as such, it is made of many operation (e.g CREATE, READ, UPDATE and DELETE USER). Also, a FEATURE has an ENTRY URL that represents an URL to that feature (to redirect an user to that feature when clicking a button/link). Each URL is mapped to a method in a Module(Controller).
- **Operation.java** - A class that represents an **OPERATION** in the web application. An operation is basically a single/basic operation such as **REGISTER USER** or **REMOVE USER**, but not necessarily a CRUD operation. Each operation has an **ENTRY URL**(an URL that shows the page to begin the operation). For example, for an **USER REGISTRATION** operation, the entry **URL** would be **/webapplicationName/moduleName(USER)/featureName(USER MANAGEMENT)/operationName(REGISTER USER)**. But an operation may need a page flow to be done. For example, an **USER REGISTRATION** operation would probably need a page with the registration form, an URL (usually mapped to a method) as an action to submit the form and a **SUCCESS/ERROR** page, to show a **SUCCESS/ERROR** message.
- **Permission.java** - A class that represents an **URL** in the system. Each Permission is related to a 1 or many **OPERATIONS**(Operation.java) to compose a **PAGE FLOW**. For example: an **USER REGISTRATION** operation would probably have the following **URLs/PERMISSIONS**:

  - **/webapplicationName/moduleName(USER)/featureName(USER MANAGEMENT)/operationName(USER REGISTRATION)/register** - An URL mapped to a method in a (CompanyNameUser)Controller to submit the form (form action) and to persist in a database usually calling a (CompanyNameUser)DAO
  - **/webapplicationName/moduleName(USER)/featureName(USER MANAGEMENT)/operationName(REGISTER USER)/success/**  - an URL mapped to a method in a Controller to show a SUCCESS MESSAGE
  - **/webapplicationName/moduleName(USER)/featureName(USER MANAGEMENT)/operationName(REGISTER USER)/error/** - an URL mapped to a method in a Controller to show an ERROR MESSAGE
- **ProfilePermission.java** - A class that represents a JOIN TABLE for a N-N relationship between Profiles and Permissions.

The problem here is that if I use Spring Security to implement access control I'm doomed to implement an User.java class (I cannot customize the name), also I would need a class for ROLES and other for AUTHORITIES. So, I can't build my own access control flow. I thought of using a SERVLET FILTER to check permissions accept/deny access. However, when I try to redirecting to a URL or just execute chain.doFilter() inside my filter, it just shows ERROR 404. I think that is because I'm using ***DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping*** to handle requests. That said, my config is as following:

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5" 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">`<display-name>cheapig</display-name>

<!-- ROOT CONTEXT DEFINITIONS -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>`
<listener>
    <listener-  class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> 

<!-- The filter to implement my access control -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.cheapig.security.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>securityFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/**</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>   

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>cheapig</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-   class>     <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/cheapig/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>cheapig</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping></web-app>
```

**root-context.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"       
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"       
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop       
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd">
<!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="latin1"/>              
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />      
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="pt"/>

</bean>

<bean id="handlerMapping"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
   <property name="interceptors">
       <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
   </property>     
</bean></beans>
```

**servlet-context:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing   infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
    <beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />
    <beans:import resource="hibernateMySQL5.xml"/>      
    <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.cheapig" />
</beans:beans>
```

**SecurityFilter.java:**

```
package br.com.cheapig.security;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

public class SecurityFilter implements Filter {

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
 }
```

So, what should I do? Should I use Spring Security? There is any way to implement my own custom process with Spring Security? Should I use an interceptor in my handler mapping instead of using a filter? I would appreciate any help/suggestions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/).  It may be a better fit for your requirements.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a look at it. For know I'll only tag it as useful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late response but here goes for future generations.

I agree with [sourcedelica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/158658/sourcedelica) that Apache Shiro is a good place to look. However, in addition, I would recommend you take a step back and look at the theory behind your problem. Essentially what you are trying to implement is a role-based access control model with users, groups, roles, and permissions. In addition, from reading your question it sounds like you have relationships between the users requesting access and the targeted resources.

With that in mind, what you need is ABAC - attribute-based access control - as defined by NIST in their report released earlier in 2014. You can [read the report here](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/).

With ABAC you can describe your users in terms of attributes - any attribute - such as role, location, age, citizenship... Similarly you can describe resources and objects that way as well as the attempted actions and the context.

This means that with attributes and ABAC you can easily implement the following authorization requirements:

- a user with the role==editor can do the action==edit on resources of type==document if and only if the user is in the same department as the resources (user.department==resource.department)
- a user can do the action==delete on a resource of type==document if and only if the user owns the document (user.id==document.owner.id) and if the status==draft.

To implement ABAC, go ahead and use [XACML](http://www.axiomatics.com/pure-xacml.html). XACML is the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language as defined by OASIS. It provides you with:

- a request/response scheme (how to ask questions and get decisions back),
- a policy language (attribute-based of course), and
- an architecture.

[image: XACML Architecture]

Google around. There are plenty of XACML resources for Java.

The benefits of using ABAC and XACML is that you end up having your access control decoupled from your business logic which means that you can change your app independently of your authorization logic and vice versa.

HTH